# Spring Batch - Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm working on a POC using Spring Boot , Spring Batch and Spring Integration.
I'm looking to build something like a crawler.

Users add information about servers(ftp,sftp ) and files to grab.
All this stuff are on a database.

My problem is : I don't know how to setup Spring Batch and Integration automatically on startup and during the running.

Any clues, examples ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of [Spring Integration Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples); some of the newer ones (e.g. barrier, kafka) use Spring Boot.

The [Spring getting started guides](https://spring.io/guides) and project sites are a good resource too.

I suggest you do some research, read docs etc, then ask a more specific question here, if you have one.